# Rotation with redundant slots in HElib

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

As described in another question [How to get exact number of slots in HElib?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/89798/how-to-get-exact-number-of-slots-in-helib-such-as-256-4096/89805#89801), get the exact number of slots with relative small parameters `m` and `q` is not easy. In fact, in HElib, we cannot decide the exact slots in the ciphertext, the function `findM()` can only help us find the smallest `m` to satisfy the security level.

Due to this concern, I have a question:
When given a `ctxt` with 16 slots, `(1, 2, 3, ..., 16)`. The expected rotation `rotate(ctxt, -2)` should be `(3, ..., 16, 1, 2)`. But if we get a ctxt with 20 slots (as described above, we usually get the ciphertext with more slots). Rotate it directly, we get `(3, ..., 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2)`, how can I get such expected format `(3, ..., 16, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)`?

Similar, for right rotation, we should get `(15, 16, 1, 2, ..., 14, 0, 0, 0, 0)` instead of `(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 16, 0, 0)` which definitely result in wrong results in the following computations.

We have to do some additional rotations, shifts and additions to implement this?

BTW, I focus on this format of rotation because I need to implement matrix multiplication. With those extra slots, it would result in bad results.

Comment: BTW, it seems that we can directly set the exact number of slots in the ciphertext in CKKS (or HEAAN).

Comment: Hi Dylan. Just a few comments. Why can't you choose the number of slots? If you choose $m$ and $p$ by yourself and pass them as arguments, Helib will accept them normally and you will have the number of slots that you want. Second: if you want your program to be efficient, instead of using the rotate function "blindly", it is a better idea to check the structure of the [plaintext hypercube](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1481.pdf#page=15) and perform rotations directly on the rows or columns that you want...

Comment: Hi @HilderVitorLimaPereira .Thanks for your reply! For the first comment, to get the exact number of slots as well as the desired security level in HElib, finally I will get large m and make it inefficient. The second comment is helpful, it's new to me and I will learn how to use it. In addition,  the rotated ciphertexts in my program are usually generated during the running of the program.

Comment: HElib actually gives access to the abstraction of operations on linear arrays with n slots, but it's at a cost. And I think it's not easy to understand the hypercube structure and operations, especially in the short term. I will have a try.